# When should you use a try-except block when handling a nested exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

If a function A calls function B and function B raises an exception.

For function A, Should I

Method 1: raise an exception bc function B raises an exception
Method 2: let function B handle the exception

Is it good practice / necessary to have a try-except block in function A if you aren't doing anything else with the failure.

```py
def validate(df):
    if df.empty():
        raise (Exception)
    return df
```

Method 1

```py
def function_a():
    df = something()
    try:
       df2 = validate(df)
    except Exception as exception:
        raise exception
    df2.to_csv()
```

Method 2

```py
def function_a():
    df = something()
    df2 = validate(df)
    df2.to_csv()
```

Comment: If you take this to the logical conclusion, you’d need to reimplement/mirror all of the exception handling of every library you use. Method 2 is a clear winner and what I use.

Comment: Your current method 1 results in the same as method 2. But sometimes one may want to transform/wrap/extend it in another exception class or may want to log it without catching it.

Comment: You're always doing something - either letting someone higher up handle it or handling the exception locally, even if that means ignoring it. What *do* you want to do? If you don't know, let it propagate

Answer (score 3):

Use Method 2.

It is unnecessary to catch an exception which you don't intend to handle, [annotate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.add_note), or log in any way, just to re-raise it again.

The pattern shown in Method 1 should *never* be used.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you whether or not to use the try-catch block in method 1. Some of the benefits to use a try-catch block in method 1 are:

- to log the exception for debugging purposes.
- to prevent the exception from propagating to the calling function.
  But sometimes it makes the code more complex. It's unnecessary to catch exceptions that you don't want to handle exceptions.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but I would just emphasize that code that simply catches and exception and only re-raises it, as method 1 is literally implemented, shouldn't be done

Answer (score 0):

Try someting -

```
try:
    funcProneToError()
except:
    #errorMessage
finally:
    #codeBlock1

def func():
    try:
       #raise error
```

Your code handles the exception twice therefore the error message is printed twice.